# Table sorter on ajax output

Tags: jquery, ajax, html-table

I am trying to show a table which is an ajax output (PHP). Even though I have added all necessary attributes to the table, tablesorter is not triggered. May I know where I went wrong. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

HTML output via ajax

```
<table border=1 width="850" id="search" class="tablesorter"> 
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <!--<th><input type="checkbox" id="selectall"/></th>-->
            <th>SNo.</th> <th>UserName</th> <th>Product Name</th><th>Price </th><th>Quantity</th><th>Total price</th><th>Quarter</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr width=700> <td>1</td> <td>user</td>  <td>androidGUI</td> <td>101</td> <td>10</td> <td>1010</td> <td>Q4-13</td></tr>
        <tr width=700> <td>2</td> <td>user </td>  <td>androidGUI</td> <td>101</td> <td>10</td> <td>1010</td> <td>Q4-13</td></tr>
        <tr width=700> <td>3</td> <td>user</td>  <td>cat6k22</td> <td>789</td> <td>5</td> <td>3945</td> <td>Q4-13</td></tr>
        <tr width=700> <td>4</td> <td>user</td>  <td>HP21</td> <td>252</td> <td>25</td> <td>6300</td> <td>Q4-13</td></tr>
        <tr width=700> <td>5</td> <td>user</td>  <td>nexus</td> <td>101</td> <td>15</td> <td>1515</td> <td>Q4-13</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

$("select").multiselect({
    selectedList: 4,
            header: false


});

}); 
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $(function () {
    var frm = $('#searchreq');
    frm.submit(function (ev) {
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
            //alert(data);
            document.getElementById("resultshower").innerHTML= data;
        }
    });
    ev.preventDefault();
});
});
});
$("#resultshower").ready(function() /*Also tried with $(document).ready still no use*/
    { 
       $("#search").tablesorter(); 
     } 
 ); 


</script>
```

The same script works without ajax calls. Please see me as novice to jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had jumbled your brackets and braces.Try this:

```
$("#resultshower").ready(function() /*Also tried with $(document).ready still no use*/
{ 
   $("#search").tablesorter(); 
}); //You went wrong here
```

And also you are calling `.ready()` function  twice before ajax. Check here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(function () { //remove this line 
.....
.....
}); // remove this line
});
```

Comment: Copy paste error it seems. Updated my code.. Still my working code has rightly placed brackets.. Still doesnt work .